# Get raw JSON from Firebase to Flutter

Tags: json, firebase, rest, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

**I'm trying to get the raw JSON from firebase database like this:**

```
 List mydata;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://opouygttgc.firebaseio.com/thing.json"),
      headers: {
          "Accept": "application.json"
      }
    );

    mydata = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    print(mydata);
```

**Im receiving this output:**

> [[Derecho Penal, Cuando un hecho delictivo se le puede atribuir o reprochar a su autor, decimos que éste es:, Si el culpable da comienzo a la ejecución del hecho delictivo practicando parte de los actos que objetivamente deberían producir el resultado, y sin embargo, éste no se produce por causas, independientes de la voluntad del autor, nos encontramos:, La negativa a cumplir una orden se castigará:, Comete delito de infidelidad en la custodia de documentos públicos

**I need to have this output instead:**

> [{0: Derecho Penal, 1: Cuando un hecho delictivo se le puede atribuir o reprochar a su autor, decimos que éste es:, 2: Si el culpable da comienzo a la ejecución del hecho delictivo practicando parte de los actos que objetivamente deberían producir el resultado, y sin embargo, éste no se produce por causas, independientes de la voluntad del autor, nos encontramos:, 3: La negativa a cumplir una orden se castigará:, 4: Comete delito de infidelidad en la custodia de documentos públicos

Before using firebase I had no trouble loading json from disk, now it messes me to get that same output format using the database response.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the structure of the data in the database that you're querying here, not just the query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database automatically converts array-like JSON structures to actual arrays when you read/write them through the REST API. There is no way to change this behavior.

If you don't want Firebase to convert your data to/from arrays, ensure that the data doesn't look like an array. For example, I usually add a short alhanumeric prefix to each key:

```
[
{
    "key_0": "Derecho Penal",
    "key_1": "Cuando un hecho delictivo se le puede atribuir o reprochar a su autor, decimos que éste es:",  
},
...
```